# How to display image in img tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I want to make the `<input type="image">` to just `<img>` tag. I am using ImageButton nested in an item template in datalist.

Here is my code:

```
    <asp:ImageButton AlternateText=" " onError="imgError(this)" name="imagebtn1" ID="imagebtn1" runat="server" Width="140" Height="140" CommandName="image1" 
CommandArgument="image"  CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl='<%# "GetImage.aspx?sourceCity=" + Eval("City") +"&ID="+ Eval("ID") +"&state="+ Eval("state") %>' OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" PostBackUrl='<%# "details.aspx?sourcecounty=" + Eval("county") +"&fname=" + Eval("col_FirstName") +"&lname=" + Eval("col_LastName") +"&ID="+ Eval("ID") +"&state="+ Eval("state") %>' />
```

When I check in Chrome using inspect element I get the following code:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$DataList1$ctl42$Image123" id="MainContent_DataList1_Image123_21" onerror="imgError(this)" src="GetImage.aspx?sourceCity=MADISON&amp;ID000113&amp;state=ALABAMA" alt=" " onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$DataList1$ctl42$Image123&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;GetImage.aspx?sourceCity=MADISON&amp;ID=000113&amp;state=ALABAMA))" style="height:140px;width:140px;">
```

Comment: `ImageUrl` can not be other than an Image Path..

Comment: @VishalSuthar: Edited the last line of my question. the tag was not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you can do is: Replace ImageButton with `<a>` tag and `<Img>` tag.

```
<a href='<%# "details.aspx?sourcecounty=" + Eval("county") +"&fname=" + Eval("col_FirstName") +"&lname=" + Eval("col_LastName") +"&ID="+ Eval("ID") +"&state="+ Eval("state") %>'>
    <img id="Image" src='<%# "GetImage.aspx?sourceCity=" + Eval("City") +"&ID="+ Eval("ID") +"&state="+ Eval("state") %>' />
</a>
```